# Error with Spring Kafka Unit Testing: Failed to determine TestUtils.createBrokerConfig()

Tags: spring, unit-testing, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka and spring-kafka-test 2.1.5.RELEASE, and I'm running the unit test example on the spring-kafka documentation, specifically this one: [Code](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_example)

On this line:

```
@ClassRule
public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, TEMPLATE_TOPIC);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError ... Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to determine TestUtils.createBrokerConfig() method
```

I'm at a loss why the example test on the official documentation isn't working, and I can't seem to find any reference on this error online. I'll be grateful if anyone has any idea what could be wrong.

This is my pom.xml, in case there is an issue I'm missing with my dependencies: https://pastebin.com/nT8j5LQ5

Comment: What kafka-clients and scala jars are you using? 2.1.5 is only compatible with 1.0.x (1.0.1) or 1.1.0. It appears you have a 1.1.0 client and something else for the scala jars (kafka_211).

Comment: Ok, by running "mvn dependency:tree" I see two jars:
**org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:1.1.0:compile**
**org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:1.0.1:test**
 and for scala:
**org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:test**

Comment: What about the `kafka_2.11` and `kafka_2.11:test` ? I don't see an override to 1.1.0 in your pom .

Comment: I'm not sure how to specify a different version for that

Comment: There's an appendix specifically for that - see my answer for a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use kafka-clients 1.1.x with Spring for Apache Kafka 2.1.x, see [Appendix A. Override Dependencies to use the 1.1.x kafka-clients](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.6.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/deps-for-11x.html).

Comment: np; I guess confluent was transitively bringing in the newer version. I have improved the error message to help in future.